# Ansible: How to wait_for service on one of many hosts?

Tags: ansible

I'm using Ansible to spin up a service on my hosts to conduct some tests. One specific host is the (initial) primary host and if the service is stopped or fails on this host it means the test is concluded. Each host has a `host_id` which is assigned in the inventory and is passed to the service that is running.

However, during execution, the primary host may change according to a list called `primary_host_ids`.
In this case, the initial primary node is no longer the one that indicates the completion of the test but one of the other nodes within this list with the matching `node_id`.

In some cases (depending on the settings for this specific test iteration), the test may not conclude within a certain time limit. If that is the case, I also want to stop it and start the next test with the new parameters.

In pseudo-code, this would be:

```
for every parameter_set in parameter_set_list:
  Extract facts from the parameter_set
  Change configuration files according to the set facts
  Start the service
  Wait for the service to finish on at least one of the potential primary nodes OR for the timeout to occur
  Stop the service
  Fetch some logs
```

I've written a role to handle the test loop:

```yaml
# roles/run-tests/main.yml
- name: Loop test
  include_tasks: run-single-test.yml
  loop: "{{ parameter_set_list }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: parameter_set

# play.yml
- hosts: all
  name: Loop test role
  roles:
    - name: Run test
      role: run-tests
```

I've tried various constructs using `include_tasks`, `block`, `until,delay,retries`, etc. but I can't find something that works. Below are some examples of what I tried:

```yaml
# roles/run-tests/run-single-test.yml
# [...Setup...]
# The following doesn't work because I cannot use `until` with `block`
# Moving the block to its own tasks file also doesn't work because `until`/`delay` cannot be used with `import_tasks` or `include_tasks` either
- name: Wait for completion on at least one primary node
  when: host_id in primary_host_ids
  block:
    - name: Check if service is no longer running
      ansible.builtin.service_facts:
      register: result

    - name: Set end flag
      when: result.ansible_facts.services['myservice.service'].state != "running"
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        _primary_completed: true
  until: _primary_completed == true
  retries: 20
  delay: 300
  ignore_errors: true
# [...Cleanup...]
```

```yaml
# roles/run-tests/run-single-test.yml
# [...Setup...]
# This loops incorrectly: The retry-until is executed first until completion or timeout and is then iterated over the different IDs
- name: Wait for completion on at least one primary host
  when: item|int == host_id|int
  ansible.builtin.service_facts:
  register: result
  until: result.ansible_facts.services['myservice.service'].state != "running"
  loop: "{{ primary_host_ids }}"
  retries: 20
  delay: 300
  ignore_errors: true
# [...Cleanup...]
```

```yaml
# roles/run-tests/run-single-test.yml
# [...Setup...]
# This would wait for the service to complete on *all* potential primary hosts
# I only want to way for *any* of them to complete
- name: Wait for completion on at least one primary host
  when: host_id in primary_host_ids
  ansible.builtin.service_facts:
  register: result
  until: result.ansible_facts.services['myservice.service'].state != "running"
  retries: 20
  delay: 300
  ignore_errors: true
# [...Cleanup...]
```

If there is no way to do this with just Ansible, is there a way to write a simple Bash script and execute multiple playbooks? I don't really care how ugly this gets but it's important that I find a way to run my tests automatically overnight.

Comment: Since the [`wait_for` module (is made for) Waits for a condition before continuing](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/wait_for_module.html), can you provide more information regarding the kind of service? Does it has a network port or PID file or an other file which maintains the state?

Comment: Regarding "_If there is no way to do this with just Ansible, is there a way to write a simple bash script and execute multiple playbooks?_" it might be possible to review [`modules/wait_for.py`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/wait_for.py) and change or enhance the logic for systemd services.

Comment: The service itself doesn't open a network port and while it does write a log file (which I retrieve later), the update on that is quite bursty. I'm assuming this might be because systemd caches a good chunk of the service's output before writing it to the file.

Comment: I *could* try to add another `printf` to my service app which generates a new file when my service is completed and then have `wait_for` look for that, but then the question is again how I can check if *any* of my hosts in my dynamic list have this file.

Comment: The last 4 [Examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/wait_for_module.html#examples) could give an idea. And the implementation would need to address a timeout and delay.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure whether I *can* just open a port due to a firewall which I have no configuration access to, but I'll see what I can do otherwise

Comment: I'm still not sure how I would check for the condition to be true on **any** of my potential primary hosts though. Using `wait_for` and checking for a file seems to me like this would check on **all** of my potential primary hosts and wait until the file is present on **all** of them

Comment: Just a note regarding `# This loops incorrectly:`, no, it is not and runs as designed. see [Ansible - How to 'wait_for' DNS to be available](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73496924/6771046).

Comment: To answer further I would need to proceed further with an actual implementation. Maybe I am going to do, but that will take time since the use case is for a distributed system. Maybe someone else here has an other idea or can show how to achieve your use case or an workaround.

Comment: There might already be something available, see [build my own loop system](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71142027/6771046).

Comment: With `This loops incorrectly` I meant that it's incorrect for my use-case.

Comment: Thanks for the linked answer, maybe with this and some locally set facts I can make something work.

Comment: Just to figure out some basic questions: 1. Do you have two lists, one with `primary_host_ids` and another with `all_host_ids`? Or are all your hosts contained in the one `primary_host_ids` list? 2. How is a primary host identified - is there anything on the host itself you could reach via ansible (e.g. a file with `stat`, a logfile entry with `lineinfile`) 3. It seems to me that these are two problems to solve: a) get the current primary host and b) check if the service on this primary host has finished. Am I right?

Comment: @Gerd that is correct. I do generate log files, but systemd only sporadically writes the output from `stdout` to these files from what I've observed. Otherwise, the services and apps are identical. I only keep the `primary_host_ids`. All hosts who cannot become primary are still in my inventory, but they don't dictate when the test should be stopped.

Comment: @Lithimlin - does the primary somehow interacts with the currently non-primaries (but potential primaries) so the others know how is currently the primary? Does this then correspond to some tcp action using some port (although you said the service does not open a port)? Maybe some default port/mechanism (like 22/ssh) is used?

Comment: Yes, there is communication between the various nodes, however via wireless modules and not via ethernet or wifi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution with the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71110337/ansible-is-ignoring-until-statement-with-import-tasks/71142027#71142027) U880D linked

```yaml
# roles/run-tests/run-single-test.yml
# [...Setup...]
- name: Invalidate finish flag
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    experiment_finished: false
  delegate_to: localhost
  delegate_facts: true

- name: Wait for completion on at least one primary node
  when: host_id in primary_host_ids
  block:
    - name: Initialize facts
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        tries_max: 20
        tries_counter: 1

    - name: Run check
      ansible.builtin.include_tasks: "./wait-for-completion.yml"


# roles/run-tests/wait-for-completion.yml
---
- name: Get service status
  when: host_id in primary_host_ids
  ansible.builtin.service_facts:
  register: result
  ignore_errors: true

- name: Check if service is completed on primary nodes
  when: 
    - host_id in primary_host_ids
    - result.ansible_facts.services['myservice.service'].state != "running"
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    experiment_finished: true
  delegate_to: localhost
  delegate_facts: true

- name: Print result
  when: 
    - host_id in primary_host_ids
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "{{hostvars['localhost']['experiment_finished']}}"

- name: increase try counter by 1
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    tries_counter: "{{ (tries_counter | int) + 1 }}"

- name: Sleep and repeat if service is not completed
  when: 
    - not hostvars['localhost']['experiment_finished']
    - (tries_counter | int) <= (tries_max | int)
    - host_id in primary_host_ids
  block:
    - name: Sleep
      ansible.builtin.pause:
        seconds: "{{ sleep_duration | default(300) }}"

    - name: Run again
      ansible.builtin.include_tasks: "./wait-for-completion.yml"
```